# bash script accessing ec2 instance

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This script required an ip and the script or file that we have to run on the remote server i gave a file in which i have wrote commands like

```
touch /root/test
ls  /root/test
```

this make the file but do not show and it is displaying an error

tcgetattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device

connection closed

How can I resolve this is there any suggestion ??

```
#!/bin/bash

# The private key used to identify this machine

IDENTITY_KEY=/home/admnew.pem

syntax()
{

    echo "Syntax: Ec2.sh server_ip scriptFile]"

    echo "For example: ./Ec2.sh server_ip scriptFile"

    exit 1
}

if [ $# -ne 2 ]

then

    echo not enough arguments

    syntax
fi


        echo "Running script $2 on $1"

        ssh -t  -t  -i $IDENTITY_KEY ec2-user@$1 sudo -i 'bash -s'  < $2

        exit
exit

echo "Done"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ssh -t  -t  -i $IDENTITY_KEY ec2-user@$1 sudo -i 'bash -s'  <<EOF
(
$(cat "$2")
)
EOF
```

e.g. wrap the script into `()`, e.g the:

```
touch /root/test
ls  /root/test
```

should be

```
(
touch /root/test
ls  /root/test
)
```

Comment: @HassaanHashmi double check (use the `-x`) how you copied my answer. Do you used the double `<<`?

Comment: no you are saying give 

(
touch   /root/test
ls  /root/test
)

in the script but i am giving this in another file lets see how this script work e.g:

ec2.sh   ip    file

in this file i gave 
touch  /root/test  and ls /root/test 
and other commands
the file is creating but ls command not showing the output